# Request format in functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, controller, functional-testing

How do I set the request format in a functional test?

I'm trying to do something like:

`get :show, :id => '1', :format => :xml`

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason you can't use symbols to define the format in tests, you must use the string version.

```
get :show, :id => '1', :format => 'xml'
```

Comment: +1 I've never understood why this is the case, but it's true that you have to use a string instead of a symbol.

Comment: Always meant to dig into the source for this and find out why.

Comment: Looks like this isn't an issue anymore. `:format => :xml` works.

Comment: To add to this answer, I was incorrectly assuming that brackets needed to surround query parameters and calling my API like this:

get :index, {"tags" => ["social networks"]}, :format => 'json'

By doing this, format was not being passed to the API.  Removing the brackets solved my issue.

get :index, "tags" => ["social networks"], :format => 'json'